# How to create a table in Angular based on a string value?

Tags: arrays, angular, multidimensional-array, ngfor, angular5

I'm using Angular 4/5 and I have to create several tables in the Angular based on a string value. Here is the model which I've made to create a table.

```
class NameValuePair {
    Name: string;
    Value: string;
}

export class Family {
    Properties: Array<NameValuePair>;
    PropertyType: string;
}
```

Given below is the hard-coded values which the table will contain.

```
export const list1: Family[] =
[
    {
      Properties: [
        {
          Name: "A",
          Value: "1"
        },

        {
          Name: "B",
          Value: "2"
        },
        {
          Name: "C",
          Value: "3"
        }
      ],
      PropertyType: "Type 1"
    },
    {
      Properties: [
        {
          Name: "A",
          Value: "10"
        },

        {
          Name: "B",
          Value: "20"
        },
        {
          Name: "C",
          Value: "30"
        }
      ],
      PropertyType: "Type 1"
    },
    {
      Properties: [
        {
          Name: "A",
          Value: "100"
        },

        {
          Name: "B",
          Value: "200"
        },
        {
          Name: "C",
          Value: "300"
        }
      ],
      PropertyType: "Type 2"
    }
  ]
```

Now, the main thing to note here is that the tables will be created based on the PropertyType. As in the above structure, the PropertyType of the first two elements of the array is same i.e. **Type 1** so 2 tables will be created. One with the caption/heading: **Type 1** and other with the caption: Type 2.
The properties[] array of the second array element will become the second row of the first table. I'm not able to find the logic on how do I create the tables based on this PropertyType string value. However, that's what I wrote in the component.html file but this logic is incorrect.

```
<div class="container pt-4" *ngFor="let element of list;let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="list[i].PropertyType == list[i+1].PropertyType">
    <div style="padding-left:250px;font-size: 20px" class="pb-2">{{element.PropertyType}}</div>

    <table id="{{element.PropertyType}}" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive pb-3 mx-auto">
      <thead style="height:40px">
        <tr align="center">
          <th *ngFor="let property of element.Properties" style="font-size: 20px">{{property.Name}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <ng-container *ngFor="let element1 of list">
          <tr align="center" *ngIf="element.PropertyType == element1.PropertyType">
            <td *ngFor="let property of element1.Properties; let propertyIndex = index" style="width: 200px">
              <ng-container [ngSwitch]="propertyIndex">         
                <div *ngSwitchDefault style="font-size: 20px">{{property.Value}}</div>
              </ng-container>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </table>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**list** here refers to the list1 const array as mentioned above. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complete logic, I did not add css, since that is not asked. Use this it is working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hd9jey

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  list1
} from './list1';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',

})
export class AppComponent {
  tableArray = [];
  constructor() {
    let tableObject = {};
    list1.forEach(i => {
      if (tableObject[i.PropertyType]) {
        tableObject[i.PropertyType].push(i);
      } else {
        tableObject[i.PropertyType] = [i];
      }
      this.tableArray = Object.entries(tableObject);
    });
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container pt-4" *ngFor="let table of tableArray;index as i">

  <div style="padding-left:250px;font-size: 20px" class="pb-2">{{table[0]}}</div>
  <table id="{{table[0]}}" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive pb-3 mx-auto">
    <thead style="height:40px">
      <tr align="center">
        <th *ngFor="let property of table[1][0].Properties" style="font-size: 20px">
          {{property.Name}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>


    <tr *ngFor="let property of table[1];" align="center">
      <td *ngFor="let va of property.Properties">
        {{va.Value}}
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to manipulate your list1 data into a nicer format first:
e.g.

```
export interface CustomTable {
  header: string,
  rows: Properties[]
}

const tables: CustomTable[] [];

list1.forEach(family => {
  // Check if this type is already in the table.
  const myTable: CustomTable = tables.find(customTable => customTable.header === family.propertyType);
  if (myTable) {
    // If it is, then add a new row
    myTable.rows.push(family.Properties);
  } else {
    // If not, create a new table
    myTable.rows.push({
      header: family.propertyType,
      rows: [family.Properties]
    });
  }
});
```

Then change your html accordingly. You probably want

```
<ng-container ngFor="let table of tables">
```

and within that somewhere a:

```
<tr *ngFor=let row of tables.rows>
```